# Background color won't take up whole element

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, padding, background-color, dropdown

I have a drop down menu button that turns grey when hovered over. However, the grey does not expand throughout the whole button, but stops at the where I set the padding.

HTML:

```css
#dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
  width: 230%;
}

#dropdown li:hover,
#dropdown li:active {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

#dropdown.active, #menu:target #dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
  <li id="menu">
    <a href="#menu">Help&#x25BE;</a>
    <ul id="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Get Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

What I want is for the grey to take up all of the drop-down menu when hovered over, as opposed to just stopping at the padding.

EDIT: I should have clarified, when I meant I want it to take up "all" of the drop down menu, I meant just the "li" when I hover over that.

Comment: so move the padding to the li ...

Comment: please fix your snippet

Comment: I changed the snippet so that the dropdown becomes visible. but I'm afraid it raises more question than it answers. I mean, why is the width 230%? And if you want "the grey to take up all of the drop-down menu when hovered over" then why do you only apply it to the individual items in the list?

Comment: I think he confused `%` for `px` and wanted to give each li a width of 230px.

Comment: The width is 230% because the background color only expands through the whole word at that width.

Comment: @RGao Did my answer help in any way? Do you need any further help?

Comment: Sorry for the late response, your answer helped and the problem is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```css
#dropdown {
  list-style: none;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
  width: 230%;
}

#dropdown:hover {
  background-color: #eee;    
}

#dropdown li:hover,
#dropdown li:active {
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

#dropdown.active, #menu:target #dropdown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav js--main-nav">
  <li id="menu">
    <a href="#menu">Help&#x25BE;</a>
    <ul id="dropdown">
      <li><a href="#">Give</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Get Help</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Get Involved</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```